# Devise: Clientside validations gem working, but text not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got an app that uses Devise and the ClientSideValidations gems.

In the form below, I've got client side validations working with devise.  I think it's working since the it's now impossible to actually submit the form.  My problem is that none of the text, such as "can't be blank" will appear next to the text field tags.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
%h3 Sign up
%br
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f|
  %h4
    = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, :validate => true
  %div
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, :validate => { :presence => :true }

  %div
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password, :validate => { :presence => :true, :length => true }
  %div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation,  :validate => { :presence => true }
  %div
    = f.submit "Sign up", id: 'button'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

When I view source, the js appears.

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
if(window.ClientSideValidations==undefined)window.ClientSideValidations={};if(window.ClientSideValidations.forms==undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.forms={};window.ClientSideValidations.forms['new_user'] = {"type":"ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder","input_tag":"<div class=\"field_with_errors\"><span id=\"input_tag\" /></div>","label_tag":"<div class=\"field_with_errors\"><label id=\"label_tag\" /></div>","validators":{"user[name]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"user[email]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"user[password]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}],"length":[{"messages":{"minimum":"is too short (minimum is 6 characters)","maximum":"is too long (maximum is 128 characters)"},"allow_blank":true,"minimum":6,"maximum":128}]}}};
//]]></script>
```

So I know it there and I believe it's doing its job, but for some reason, I'm just not seeing the error messages I would expect when I leave a field blank.

Comment: It may be related to initializer. Can we see client side initializer file?

Comment: Who are you, so wise in the ways of science?!  That's exactly right.  I still had the block commented out for giving each input field its own validation message. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, my comment was not a real answer.